# Since last kernel update (5.15.0-52-generic), screen resolution is broken, and network not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

Other kernel modules are probably not working either. Haven't confirmed but I wouldn't be surprised if e.g. USB didn't work either.

Going into the GRUB menu and loading the previous version (5.15.0-47-generic) works fine. I've had riffs on this issue ever since I dist-upgraded to 22.04.1 LTS. When first asking in #ubuntu in IRC I got asked to uninstall `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` that was left dangling from the previous release, one thing I notice is that I don't have a corresponding 22.04 package, but since it works fine with the older kernel version I think that might not be the issue?

Also, possibly unrelated but I had a mess of nvidia drivers, installed `nvidia-515` and got rid of everything else and ever since I've been having video glitches.

Here's some checks I made. I see no obvious issues, but I don't know much to be honest.

```
 ❯ apt list --installed | grep '^linux' | less
linux-base/jammy,jammy,now 4.5ubuntu9 all [installed,automatic]
linux-firmware/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,now 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.6 all [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-5.11.0-40-generic/now 5.11.0-40.44 amd64 [installed,local]
linux-headers-5.11.0-40/now 5.11.0-40.44 all [installed,local]
linux-headers-5.15.0-47-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-47.51 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-5.15.0-47/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security,jammy-security,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-47.51 all [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.11.0-40-generic/now 5.11.0-40.44 amd64 [installed,local]
linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-47.51 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.15.0-52-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-52.58 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-libc-dev/jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-52.58 amd64 [installed]
linux-modules-5.11.0-40-generic/now 5.11.0-40.44 amd64 [installed,local]
linux-modules-5.15.0-47-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-47.51 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-modules-5.15.0-52-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-52.58 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-40-generic/now 5.11.0-40.44 amd64 [installed,local]
linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-47-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-47.51 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.11.0-40-generic/now 5.11.0-40.44+1 amd64 [installed,local]
linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.15.0-47-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-47.51 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.15.0-52-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-52.58+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-signatures-nvidia-5.11.0-40-generic/now 5.11.0-40.44+1 amd64 [installed,local]
linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-47-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-47.51 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-52-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-52.58+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-sound-base/jammy,jammy,now 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu7 all [installed,automatic]
```

```
❯ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

dkms status output with the non-working kernel running:

```
$ dkms status
nvidia/510.85.02, 5.15.0-47-generic, x86_64: installed
```

with the older, working kernel, it's exactly the same:

```
$ dkms status
nvidia/510.85.02, 5.15.0-47-generic, x86_64: installed
```

obviously that older kernel version on the newer kernel run looks suspect

Comment: What is the output of `dkms status`?  Please add that to your question.  Thank you!

Comment: @Terrance there it is, sorry about how long this took. Indeed that looks weird

Comment: I see the driver never carried over into your new kernel update.  I don't see the network driver though. Strange.  Anyways, you can install the driver into the newer Kernel by running `sudo dkms install -m nvidia -v 510.85.02 -k 5.15.0-52-generic` where I am assuming from your output that you have the Kernel version of `5.15.0-52-generic` installed.

Comment: thanks, @Terrance. The kernel headers were missing, that might be why dkms didn't upgrade the drivers, I guess. IDK.

Comment: Did you install the Kernel headers?  If not, they are installed by doing `sudo apt install linux-headers-5.15.0-52-generic`

Comment: Still no go. dkms status now shows The 52 version installed but I'm still running in low resolution. IDK if this helps, but I have my HDD encrypted, and the difference is already there on the password input prompt

Comment: Sorry the back and forth takes so long, but this is my work box and I don't quite find the time to take off and try things out, it's very annoying